# Creating a menu interface to update an sde feature class in ArcMap using arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, query, context-menu

I work in electrical utilities and we have stacks of paper records that need to be updated into an existing SDE feature class attribute table. My problem is that someone in the city's GIS office would like me to create a simple interface where anyone with access can search a for a pole number and edit records in that row of the attribute table with a menu-like interface. He/she's reasoning is that employees with little GIS experience won't make mistakes with the data. Is it possible to construct something like this that would provide any benefits over starting an editing session and just keying values into the attribute table?

Comment: This is definitely doable. Have you considered something like the ArcGIS Collector App?

Comment: I have not! I will look into it. Thanks for replying. Also, It would be much easier if this were done via desktop instead of mobile phone considering we're in an office. Just a thought.

Comment: You should take a look at the various app options at https://www.arcgis.com/features/apps/. I have not tried it yet, but the Survey123 beta http://survey123.esri.com/ might be a better option for you than Collector (since Survey123 cab be used by desktop end users). But... it is beta so it really should not be used for production.

Comment: Python has many GUI packages that can be used in a script or desktop add-in.  Look at TKINTER package as an example.

Answer (score 1):

I thought about it some more and even just ArcGIS Online would be a potential solution. I know this will work with SDE datasets because I created a Collector application that directly edits features stored in our SQL Server database. I can access them through my ArcGIS Online account with the Collector App on my iPhone (can use Android too). This also requires ArcGIS Server (service should be published using "Feature Access") so be aware of that. Here are some good links.

Collector Documentation
http://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector/

A Tutorial
http://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector/ios/collect-data/collect-tutorial.htm

You could also create a map this way with ArcGIS Server and just edit the webmap online (another option) but it is just as easy to set it up following the tutorial.